# Selecting subset of collection with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

In this sample how to get only Foos that have any active Bar and return only the active Bars in the collection?

One possible solution is something like this, but it requires recreate the Foo elements:

```
fooList
    .Where(f => f.Bars.Any(b => b.IsActive))
    .Select(f => new Foo()
    {
        Name = f.Name,
        Bars = f.Bars.Where(b => b.IsActive).ToList()
    });
```

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Edit 1**

The objective is to get only Foos with any active Bar **and** for these Foos, just the Bars that was active.

```
FooA
    Bar1 (Active)
    Bar2 (Inactive)
FooB
    Bar3 (Inactive)
    Bar4 (Inactive)
FooC
    Bar5 (Active)
    Bar6 (Active)
```

Disired result:

```
FooA
    Bar1 (Active)
FooC
    Bar5 (Active)
    Bar6 (Active)
```

As pointed theres many simple solutions, but I'm wondering if the Linq has any way to do this without retrieve all Bars and then drop the inactive in a loop-like after all Bars was retrieve in memory.

Comment: Well yes, you have to create new `Foo` objects - because the existing `Foo` objects may have inactive `Bar` references. What would you want the solution to actually return, if not new objects? Do you only really care about the `Bar` objects? (If so, that's easy.) If you could describe the "shape" of the result you want, the implementation should be simple.

Comment: Just wondering if there's some linq specific solution for this kind os problem (always trying to learn something new) :)

Comment: Well without more context, we don't really know what you mean by "this kind of problem". LINQ doesn't allow a single object to simultaneously not have any active `Bar` objects and still retains its previous information, if that's what you were thinking...

Comment: Do you need the Foos containing the active Bars in the final result, or just a sequence of active Bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

Adding the Data to List

```
List<Foo> employees = new List<Foo>();
Foo employee = new Foo();
employee.Name = "Emp1";
employee.Bars = new List<Bar>();
employee.Bars.Add(new Bar { Name = "Alpesh", IsActive = true });
employee.Bars.Add(new Bar { Name = "Krunal", IsActive = true });
employee.Bars.Add(new Bar { Name = "Karthik", IsActive = false });
employee.Bars.Add(new Bar { Name = "Rakesh", IsActive = true });
employees.Add(employee);
```

Fetching the Active Data Only

```
List<Foo> newList = employees.Select(m => new Foo
        {
            Name = m.Name,
            Bars = m.Bars.Where(u => u.IsActive == true).ToList()
        }).ToList();
return newList;
```

Comment: you can use this like : var ty = employees.Select(m => new Foo { Name = m.Name, Bars = m.Bars.Where(u => u.IsActive == true).ToList() }).ToList(); also

Comment: How would I get a subset of data when I don't know the exact value? For example, I need to process user data where each user would have multiple records. So I want to chunk off a group of data for each user and pass that into a function to process that user.

Comment: @James In your case, there is a list inside Bar Object, where I have used only 2 properties, you can select the list directly by name or unique id and process that using loop individually. The list can be selected the way I have selected active persons after that you can loop through.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-create `Foo's` then use a loop

```
foreach(var foo in fooList.Where(f => f.Bars.Any(b => b.IsActive)))
{
    foo.Bars = foo.Bars.Where(b => b.IsActive).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of the active `Bar` instances pulled from all `Foo`, but don't need to know which `Foo` instances they came from, this should work for you:

```
var activeBars = fooList.SelectMany(f => f.Bars)
                        .Where(b => b.IsActive)
                     // .Distinct() /* eliminate duplicates if you want */
                        .ToList();
```

The `SelectMany` operator concatenates the `Bars` from every `Foo` into a single sequence.  The `Where` operator filters out just the active ones.  `ToList()` forces a snapshot to be populated immediately.

This gives you a `List<Bar>` containing only the `Bar` instances where `IsActive == true`.  If two or more `Foo` might contain the same `Bar`, and you want to eliminate those duplicates, then add a `Distinct()` operator before `ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the Foo objects in the select clause.  Lambdas don't have to be simple expressions, they can contain multiple statements.

```
var cleanedList = fooList.Where(f => f.Bars.Any(b => b.IsActive))
                         .Select(f => {
                                          f.Bars.RemoveAll(b => !b.IsActive); 
                                          return f;
                                      }
                                 );
```